# CSS zooming and viewport

Tags: html, css, zooming

In the [following fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/egegeg/rp0caq9x/7/) whose [full-page result can be loaded from here](https://jsfiddle.net/egegeg/rp0caq9x/7/show) when zoomed-in `<div class="header">` grows "internally" : its height changes but its width always spans the viewport, while `<div class="wrapper1">` and its children grow beyond the viewport.

How can I make `header` to grow beyond the viewport when zoomed in proportion to `wrapper1` and its children and how can I make the opposite where `wrapper1` and its children don't grow beyond the viewport just like `header`.